# Netbeans Ant build task to take multiple values in one input dialog

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

Upon building a jar/war etc I'd like to show the user the current version (stored in a properties file in the project) and already read into ns.MAJORVERSION and ns.MINORVERSION and allow them to update before writing to the manifest. 
Ideally I'd like to take two inputs at once like so...

```
<input
    message="Current Version is ${ns.MAJORVERSION} :${ns.MINORVERSION} update?"
    addproperty="new.majorversion"
    addproperty="new.minorversion"
/>
```

However this is not allowed and fails with an error saying 'Attribute "addproperty" was already specified'
Is there anyway of doing this in one dialog (I presume netbeans is setting the default input handler as a pop up dialog) or do I just need to have two inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have single input as version in a format like MAJORVERSION.MINORVERSION and then split them in two separate properties.

PropertyRegex from ant contrib may come handy (http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html)

Alternatively, yes, separate in two distinct inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'd thought of that I think its what I'll do as the two inputs is a bit clunky. Thanks.